# Find in Custom Class Vector

Tags: c++, class, vector, stl, iterator

I am practicing this code(from LeetCode) to be better in C++. Unfortunately, I am unable to get '**find**' to work correctly.
This code is used to search **word** from a vector of vector of type char (i.e. **board**) without visiting the same letter twice(**visitedSoFar** keeps a track of the x,y positions of the letters visitedSoFar).

 A vector of class **Node** is used to store the positions visited so far.
Here is the code snippet I have written:

```
class Node{
    private:
        int x;
        int y;

    public:
        Node(int a, int b):x(a),y(b){};
        bool operator==(Node newNode){
            if(this->x == newNode.x && this->y == newNode.y)
                return true;
            else 
                return false;
        }
};

class Solution {
public:
    bool exist(vector<vector<char>>& board, string word) {
        vector <Node> visitedSoFar;

        for(int r =0; r< board.size(); r++){
            for(int c=0; c<board[r].size(); c++){
                if(board[r][c] == word.at(0)){

                if(search(board, word, visitedSoFar, board[r].size(), r, c))
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private:
    bool search(vector<vector<char>>& board, string word, vector<Node>& visitedSoFar, int size, int r, int c){
        Node newNode(r,c);
        visitedSoFar.push_back(newNode);

        if(word.size() == 1)
            return true;

        Node toSearch1(r-1,c);
        if(r-1 >= 0 && find(visitedSoFar.begin(), visitedSoFar.end(), toSearch1) == visitedSoFar.end()){
            if(board[r-1][c] == word.at(1))
                if(search(board, word.substr(1), visitedSoFar, size, r-1, c))
                    return true;
        }

        Node toSearch2(r+1,c);
        if(r+1 < size && find(visitedSoFar.begin(), visitedSoFar.end(), toSearch2) == visitedSoFar.end()){
            if(board[r+1][c] == word.at(1))
                if(search(board, word.substr(1), visitedSoFar, size, r+1, c))
                    return true;
        }

        Node toSearch3(r,c-1);
        if(c-1 >= 0 && find(visitedSoFar.begin(), visitedSoFar.end(), toSearch3) == visitedSoFar.end()){
            if(board[r][c-1] == word.at(1))
                if(search(board, word.substr(1), visitedSoFar, size, r, c-1))
                    return true;
        }

        Node toSearch4(r,c+1);
        if(c+1 < size && find(visitedSoFar.begin(), visitedSoFar.end(), toSearch4) == visitedSoFar.end()){
            if(board[r][c+1] == word.at(1))
                if(search(board, word.substr(1), visitedSoFar, size, r, c+1))
                    return true;
        }
        visitedSoFar.pop_back();
        return false;
    }
};
```

If I comment the find I get the correct output, but this would not work for all test cases.

Thank You.

**Edit**
In method search, corrected if statement to check against size for (r+1) and (c+1).

**Edit**
The word can be constructed from letters of sequentially adjacent cell, where "adjacent" cells are those horizontally or vertically neighboring. The same letter cell may not be used more than once.

**Edit**
Design Error: The find operation should not be able to find(indicating that the node has not been visited so far) to then proceed with search in it. Hence altered find to be == visitedSoFar.end() rather than != visitedSoFar.end().

Comment: You didn't give us a `main` program, the data you're testing, or the expected output. -- *I am practicing this code(from LeetCode) to be better in C++*  -- and to be "better in C++" requires you to acquire debugging skills by learning how to use the debugger, and not just write a program, hope it works, and then go to SO if it doesn't work.

Comment: Suggestion: class `Solution` doesn't make much sense, it stores no state. It's methods look almost like a C code. I would change the `class` to `namespace`, or make `board` and `visitedSoFar` class members

Comment: Are you sure you want to check c+1 and r+1 >=0 ? shouldn't it be checked against exceeding the dimension of the board? something like c+1 < n  r+1 < n etc. Also in your operator== of class Node pass the Node by reference.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am coming from a background of C and hence my style of writing code is C-like.

Comment: @PrameetSinghKohli -- I never mentioned `C` programming, but more importantly, you still didn't provide a [mcve],emphasis on **complete**.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie:
Since I was practicing this online on a website I do not have a main function provided by them. I am currently building a main and shall edit the code to include it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a simpler design of your solution.
The idea behind checking every boardpoint is most likely unnecessary work, right? Using your approach you are constantly checking if the work has already been done. This checking includes a linear search through your board (every node will be saved at some time) for every search step. This means pretty much you can avoid checking it most likely, since the work to be done is almost the same.

Therefor a fastly coded solution would be like this.

```
bool row_contains_word(vector<char> const& row, string word)
{
  if(word.size() > row.size())
    throw std::invalid_argument("Word is longer then the row!!");

  // linear search for the word in board
  for(int i = 0; i < row.size() - word.size(); ++i) // start point
  {
    // check realtive to the start point if its the word there
    for(int j = 0; j < word.size(); ++j) 
    {
      if(row[i+j] != word[j])
        break; // we can continue to check the next position
      // last position we check here, and match means its the word
      else if(j == (word.size() - 1) && row[i+j] == word[j])
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
```

Using this function (i dont think its a really good way to accomplish it, but just to have an example) you can simply loop:

```
for(int r = 0; r < board.size(); ++r)
{
  if(row_contains_word(board[r], word))
     return true;
}
// and same with colums as well
```

As mentioned in the comments, Solution isnt a candidate for a class.
It could be written like this:

```
namespace Solution
{
  bool search(vector<vector<char>> const& board, string word); // implementaion follows

  namespace // anonymous namespace, not accessible from the outside world, but only this compilation unit(.cpp file)
  {
    bool row_contains_word(vector<char> const& row, string word);
    bool col_contains_word(/*vector<char> const& row,*/ string word); // this needs more work, since the col is a little different
  }
}
```

This can hide the implementation from the searching from the interface of deciding if a word is contained in the board.

Comment: Thank you Black Moses and @jonas_toth for directing me towards namespace. Indeed it is the correct way to maintain a code instead of using 'class solution'.
However, since I am using a website to practice coding C++, I have little say in the template already given to me to practice on.
For now, I am concentrating why whether find is implemented properly or am I missing anything here ?